# Topology .. cluster points

Tags: general-topology

prove that if x is a cluster point of A unoin B then x is a cluster point of A or B

I proved it by contrapositive but I want to prove it with direct proof

Comment: this is my proof : let x be a cluster point of AUB then for any poen set u contains x.. u intersection {A UB-{x}} is not empty this implies《 u intersection {A-{x}} 》U 《 u intersection {B-{x}} 》 is not empty so x is a cluster point of A or a cluster point of B my teacher says that this proof is not correct and I have no idea why !!!!

Comment: It is not enough to prove that any given neighbourhood contains infinitely many points of A or infinitely many points of B. You have to show that either (1) *every* neighbourhood contains infinitely many points of A, or (2) *every* neighbourhood contains infinitely many points of B. That needs slightly more than you have done.

Comment: thank you that was very informative

Answer (score 0):

Well, suppose $x$ is a cluster point of $A\cup B,$ but not a cluster point of $B$ (since if it is, we're done). Now apply the definition of cluster point, and its negation, to prove that $x$ is a cluster point of $A$.